# VoIP app / restore connection on reboot

Tags: ios, voip

I developed a VoIP app and I read from the documentation that a VoIP app automatically restarts on phone reboot. However, DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not called on reboot so my connection cannot be restored.

The only way to reconnect is to start it manually it seems.

I can see the app is in memory, because it is quite quick to start when I click on it, but I thought the app should be able to restore its connection without user intervention.

Any thoughts? What am I missing? Is there another callback in AppDelegate that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The app is capable of receiving remote notifications in this state. 
According to

[Voip Pushkit notification will not re-launch the app if it was force-quitted and device was rebooted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603364/voip-pushkit-notification-will-not-re-launch-the-app-if-it-was-force-quitted-and)

this seems to work in most cases.

I have not found any official documents on this.

EDIT:

Here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH30-SW1

is the official documentation on pushkit, which describes that the app is woken up, even if it not running or in background mode.